# Setting PUT request body with PHP

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use the Google Sheets API's spreadsheets.values.update (https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/update) method to insert data into a spreadsheet.

I've already acquired a correctly scoped access token, and now I'm trying to send a PUT request via cURL. I'm using the PHP curl wrapper (https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class) but plain PHP would also be great.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$curl = new Curl();
    $curl->setHeader("Authorization","Bearer ".json_decode($a4e->user->google_token)->access_token);
    $curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"values": [["Elizabeth", "2", "0.5", "60"]]}');
    $curl->put('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/11I1xNv8cHzBGE7uuZtB9fQzbgrz4z7lIaEADfta60nc/values/Sheet1!A1', array(
        'valueInputOption' => 'USER_ENTERED'    
    ));

    if ($curl->error) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $curl->errorCode . ': ' . $curl->errorMessage;
    }
    else {
        echo json_encode($curl->response);
    }
```

The cURL request executes successfully, and returns the following:

> {"spreadsheetId":"11I1xNv8cHzBGE7uuZtB9fQzbgrz4z7lIaEADfta60nc","updatedRange":"Sheet1!A1"}

However, it does not update the data in the sheet.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I ran the parameters through Postman (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) and exported the following code:

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/11I1xNv8cHzBGE7uuZtB9fQzbgrz4z7lIaEADfta60nc/values/Sheet1!A1?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\"range\":\"Sheet1!A1\",\"majorDimension\":\"ROWS\",\"values\":[[\"x\",\"x\",\"x\",\"x\",\"x\"]]}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "authorization: Bearer {token}",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/json",
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

And it finally works! The content-type: application/json is absolutely essential, as per RomanPerekhrest's suggestion. The request doesn't update anything without it.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you are successfully authenticated using OAuth? I would look into your put URL. You are saying "Sheet1!A1" yet you are entering data that looks like it would span across multiple cells. So I would try adjusting "Sheet1!A1" to include an actual rage of cells since you have many pieces of data you are importing. Normally the response should look similar to [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/UpdateValuesResponse). Because it doesn't have any of that last information in your response it looks like the cells you are specifying to write to aren't correct.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the comment. Yes, authentication is successful, and I am able to read data with no problems from the same spreadsheet. The migration docs here (https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/migration#add_a_new_row_of_data) say "The range specified need only refer to the first cell in the row; the API infers the cells to update based on the values provided with the request." so I don't think that should be a problem..

Answer (score 1):

At first:

- you've called `$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"values":
  [["Elizabeth", "2", "0.5", "60"]]}');` passing in a regular string.
  But curl `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option accepts it's value to be
  urlencoded string like `'para1=val1&para2=val2&...'` or an
  associative array of data(key/value pairs)

Secondly:

- the `put` function from that library(`php-curl-class`) `function
  put($url, $data = array()) ...` considers its second argument as post
  data.
  As you passed in an array of data when calling `put` method - you've overwrote previous post data set by `$curl->setOpt(CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ....`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. The API requires a single query parameter to be set, "valueInputOption", which I am trying to set using the second argument in the php-curl-class function. However, it also seems to require a JSON encoded string in the BODY of the PUT request.. I'm not sure how to include both of these elements in my request..

Comment: if it "require a JSON encoded string in the BODY of the PUT request." have you tried to set the array `array('valueInputOption' => '{"values": [["Elizabeth", "2", "0.5", "60"]]}' ))` as  a second argument to `put` function?

Comment: "valueInputOption" has to be one of the following: "RAW" or "USER_ENTERED" (as per: https://developers.google.com/sheets/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption)

Comment: I've changed my PUT request to the following: `$curl->put('https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/11I1xNv8cHzBGE7uuZtB9fQzbgrz4z7lIaEADfta60nc/values/Sheet1!A1?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED','{"values": [["Elizabeth", "2", "0.5", "60"]]}');` - the cURL request executes successfully, but the spreadsheet data still isn't updating :-/

Comment: also, try to set additional header `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` specifying content-type as `json`

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you very much for all your help and suggestions!