# INPUT_VALUE_OPTION_UNSPECIFIED issue on Google Spread Sheet Api on PHP Client

Tags: php, google-client, google-sheets-api

According to the question asked by "Setting PUT request body with PHP" [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38029986/setting-put-request-body-with-php/38030164#38030164), I use the method mentioned in the answer to use curl to post the content to my spreadsheet by php.

And I got the following error message in return, so as the result from the Postman query. The content of this spreadsheet should be kept private.

> {
>     "error": {
>       "code": 401,
>       "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials.",
>       "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
>     }
>   }

So I want to use the method mentioned in the quickstart guide [2](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/dotnet#step_3_set_up_the_sample) to organize the Postbody in PHP.

Below is my code

```
$range = "general!A9:E";
$vRan = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
$vRan->setMajorDimension("ROWS");
$vRan->setRange($range);
$val = array
  (
    array(time(), "General", "PHPName", "PHPCompany","mail@php.com")
 );
$vRan->setValues($val);

$type="USER_ENTERED";
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $vRan,array($type));
```

And I got those error messages

> Illegal string offset 'type' in /Users/user1/Sites/gas/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 151
>   PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'location' in /Users/user1/Sites/gas/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 154
>   PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'location' in /Users/user1/Sites/gas/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 156
>   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Error calling PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[ID]/values/general%21A9%3AH: (400) Invalid valueInputOption: INPUT_VALUE_OPTION_UNSPECIFIED' in /Users/user1/Sites/gas/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Http/REST.php:110

How could I manage to correctly organize the Iuput value option?

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue and successfully put the data onto google spread sheet by modifying the data structure of the last parameter from array("RAW") to array("valueInputOption"=>"RAW")

```
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->update($spreadsheetId, $range, $vRan, array("valueInputOption"=>$type));
```

Comment: Here is another answer to the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025841/trying-to-append-a-row-to-a-google-spreadsheet-in-php/38247136#38247136